# Android - While switching between two activities, the calling order of lifecycle methods of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to start an Activity (SECOND Activity) from another Activity (FIRST Activity) by calling `startActivity(intent)`. Before I actually do it, I found people say that the lifecycle methods are called in the following order:

```
FIRST Activity onCreate
FIRST Activity onStart
FIRST Activity onResume
FIRST Activity onPause
SECOND Activity onCreate
SECOND Activity onStart
SECOND Activity onResume
FIRST Activity onStop
```

Is the `SECOND Activity onResume` always called before `FIRST Acitivity onStop`? I thought

```
FIRST Activity onPause
FIRST Activity onStop
SECOND Activity onCreate
SECOND Activity onStart
SECOND Activity onResume
```

will be called, but it seems not.

Also, if I just switch between two activities,

```
FIRST Activity onPause
SECOND Activity onRestart
SECOND Activity onStart
SECOND Activity onResume
FIRST Activity onStop
```

Are the methods always called in this order?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the documentation, SECOND.onResume() is supposed to be called before FIRST.onStop()
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#coordinating-activities
(**Coordinating activities** section)

Comment: But bear in mind, some of the methods may never be called like `onStop()`. Read documentation of each method carefully before implementing your code.

Comment: @OneWorld Do you have any sources for that? I can't find anywhere saying that `onStop()` may never be called. I know that `onDestroy()` will not be called if the  process is in the background and the system decides to kill it without calling all the methods, but can't find any such statements about `onStop()`.

Comment: @Thorbear `FIRST.onStop` will not be called if `SECOND` does not cover the whole screen and so `FIRST` stays paused and never gets to the stopped state.

Also, link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 58):

Suppose There are two activities `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

Then this order will always remain same everytime.

// when you start FirstActivity

> (1) OnCreate() ->  OnStart()  ->  OnResume() of `FirstActivity` will be called

when you start SecondActivity using
**startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class))**

> (2) OnPause() of **FirstActivity** will be called and then
>
> (3) OnCreate() ->  OnStart()  ->  OnResume() of **SecondActivity** will be Called then
>
> (4) OnStop() of  **FirstActivity** will be called

// when you press back button on **SecondActivity**

> (5) OnPause() of  **SecondActivity** will be called then
>
> (6) OnRestart() -> OnStart() -> OnResume() of  **FirstActivity** will be called then
>
> (7) onStop() -> onDestroy() of  **SecondActivity** will be called

```
 Note: 

 (1) OnPause() will be called first when you navigate to any other activity.
 
 (2) OnStop() will be called when activity is no longer Visible on screen.
```

Comment: Best explanation so far!

Answer (score -2):

***First opens Activity:***
onCreate(),OnStart(),onResume()

***User Clicks backButton():***
onPause(),onStop(),onDestroy()

***Navigating to another screen:***

**First Screen:**: onPause(),onStop()

**Second Screen:** onCreate(),OnStart(),onResume()

***Presses Backbutton in Activity2:***

**Second Screen:** onPause(),onStop() ,onDestroy()

**First Screen:** onRestart(), onStart(), onResume()

**User locks the device:** onPause(),onStop()

**Again Opens lock:** onRestart(), onStart(), onResume()